# How to add NTSync support to both kernel and Wine?

Tags: kernel, wine, compiling

Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. How can I apply NTSync patches for kernel and Wine? I've built a few custom kernels years ago (16.04 or 18.04, I don't remember), but I have no idea how to apply NTSync patches.

Comment: Are you sure NTSync isn't already integrated?  You'd have to build a custom kernel setup for 22.04 probably from Mainline to get custom patches in.  As for Wine, you'd have to probably patch *Wine itself* which is a completely different beast.

Comment: It's barely possible to miss /dev/ntsync if there was any. Also, apt source [kernel name] provides sources without any mention of "ntsync" word. Can it be even done in 22.04, or have I to upgrade from LTS to a newer build first? Is apt source enough for the newest distro, or Git is required? Or maybe this patch must be applied manually (not included yet, even in Git)? About Wine, yep, I will have to patch it, too. But first of all, I have to build the kernel.